# Custom user role cannot see or modify featured image

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, user-roles

I have created a custom post type called `Event` and I have enabled support for featured images in my `functions.php` file, but still my custom user role can not see the featured image meta box on the edit page for an event. If a user logges in as administrator the `Featured Image` meta box is displayed without any errors.

Here is my code to register the CPT:

```
add_action('init', 'event_post_init');

function event_post_init() {
  // array of all capabilities for our CPT
  $capabilities = array(
     'publish_posts' => 'publish_events',
     'edit_posts' => 'edit_events',
     'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_events',
     'delete_posts' => 'delete_events',
     'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_events',
     'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_events',
     'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_events',
     'edit_post' => 'edit_event',
     'delete_post' => 'delete_event',
     'read_post' => 'read_event',
   );

   // register the CPT
   register_post_type( 'event',
      array(
         'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Event')
         ),
         'public' => true,
         'has_archive' => true,
         'show_ui' => true,
         'menu_position' => 8,
         'capability_type' => array('event', 'events'),
         'capabilities' => $capabilities,
         'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
         'map_meta_cap' => true,
         'hierarchical' => true,
      )
   );
}
```

and here is how I setup my custom user role:

```
function create_event_admin_role(){
   add_role('event_admin', 'Event Administrator', array(
     'publish_events' => false,
     'edit_events' => true,
     'edit_others_events' => false,
     'delete_events' => false,
     'delete_others_events' => false,
     'read_private_events' => true,
     'edit_published_events' => true,
     'read' => true,
     'assign_terms' => true,
     'edit_terms' => true,
     'manage_terms' => true,
     'read_private_pages' => true
   )
  );
}
```

The strange thing is that if I look at the markup for the edit page I can see the `#postimagediv` element but for some reason it is hidden. Here is the markup in the page:

```
<div class="postbox  hide-if-js" id="postimagediv" style="">
   <div title="Click to toggle" class="handlediv"><br></div>
   <h3 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span>Featured Image</span></h3>
   <div class="inside">
     <p class="hide-if-no-js">
       <a class="thickbox" id="set-post-thumbnail" href="http://example.com/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=662&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=1&amp;width=753&amp;height=294" title="Set featured image">Set featured image</a>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css that actually hides the meta box:

```
#postimagediv {
   display: hidden !important;
}
```

Notice that I **have** enabled `Featured Image` under `Screen Options`.

Perhaps I also should point out that I have tried giving the above role the `upload_files` privilege using the following code:

```
function extend_event_admin_role() {
  $role = get_role('event_admin');

  $role->add_cap('upload_files');
}
```

Another thing to point out is that if I **do** add the `upload_files` permission, then `Featured Image` is visible under `Screen Options` and also other meta boxes which has support for media has a `Add Media` button, which if I set `upload_files` to `false` disappears.

[image]

[image]

If I change the code in `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php` which add the featured image metabox then I can tell that it's really calling `add_metabox()`:

```
if ( $thumbnail_support && current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ):
  add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Featured Image'), 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', null, 'side', 'low');
  print 'Support for Featured Image';
  exit;
endif;
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve here I am confused? What problems you are facing please update one by one with source code so we understand.

Comment: The question should be pretty clear, users with the custom role `event_admin` cannot see `Featured Image`

Comment: Have you tried my solution? because its working for me.

Comment: Since I'm using alot of special privileges such as `edit_others_events`, `publish_events` and so on, I think it will be complex to clone a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally tracked the problem down to an activated plugin called [`Revisionary`](https://sv.wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/). The function that is responsible for hiding the `postimagediv` element is `act_hide_admin_divs` located in `revisionary/admin/admin_rvy.php`. What the function does is to hide metaboxes with content that doesn't support revisions.

In order to show the featured image for my specific role I used the `rvy_hidden_meta_boxes` filter:

```
add_filter('rvy_hidden_meta_boxes', 'revisor_show_featured_image_box');

function revisor_show_featured_image_box($unrevisable_css_ids) {
   $key = array_search('postimagediv', $unrevisable_css_ids, true);
   unset($unrevisable_css_ids[$key]);

   return $unrevisable_css_ids;
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problematic plugin, no wonder I couldn't re-create this behavior on a vanilla install ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Users that are only assigned to your `event_admin` role, don't have the `upload_files` capability, needed to display the *featured image* meta box.

Here's the relevant code from the core:

```
if ( $thumbnail_support && current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) )    // <-- Notice this check
    add_meta_box( 
        'postimagediv', 
        esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->featured_image ),             
        'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 
        null, 
       'side', 
       'low'
    );
```

Note that if you later try to add the option:

```
'upload_files' => true
```

to your `add_role()` setup, it might not update, since it's cached in the `wp_user_roles` option.

You therefore need to update the database to adjust it:

- use [`remove_role()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_role) and then `add_role()` again,
- use the [`add_cap()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) method of the `\WP_Role` class.

It might also be possible to use  filters like [`user_has_cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap) to adjust this dynamically.

Comment: I have already tried to give the `upload_files` permission, but the issue remains.

Comment: Can you share how you did that? Maybe you're still using the cached `wp_user_roles` option values?

Comment: ... that's why the Codex recommends running `add_role`/`remove_role`  on theme/plugin activation/deactivation. @Cyclone

Comment: Checkout my updated answer, I have tried to delete the role using `remove_role()`. The strange thing is that `current_user_can('upload_files`)` should return true, since this permission is given to the user and he also has the ability to upload media files in other meta boxes?

Comment: It sounds you haven't forgot to add `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` in your theme, since you can see the debug print. Any javascript errors? Did you try this on a clean install with the default theme? @Cyclone

Comment: Nope, I have not. And I can assure you that `add_meta_box('postimagediv', ...);` really gets called. Like I stated in my question, the element exist but is for some reason hidden.

Comment: I tested it on a vanilla install and it looks like the  `postimagediv` is showing/visible for a user with only the `event_admin` role with the additional `upload_files` capability. => it worked to set a featured image - but currently I'm not sure what's different in your case ;-)  @Cyclone

Comment: I'm starting to think this might be because some plugin I am using.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you need a custom-post type `Event` + `featured_image` + `Custom Role`, what I don't understand is capability_type event and events unless and until you are customizing to much, whats the reason here for such customization?

What I did here is cloned editor role to `event_amdin` with all its capabilities and make capability_type to page as you are using page-attributes in your question.

Test: Created two users *test* as *contributor* and *cyclone* as *Event Administrator* and its working fine. Please provide more information about your need so I update this answer. Thanks!

**Edit 1** : Updated code, check edit 1 start/end section into `cloneUserRole` function.

Happy Coding!!

```
function cloneUserRole()
{
    global $wp_roles;

    if (!isset($wp_roles))
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

        $editor      = $wp_roles->get_role('editor');
        // Adding a new role with all editor caps.
        $wp_roles->add_role('event_admin', 'Event Administrator', $editor->capabilities);

        // edit 1 start : updated to add cap to new user role
        $event_admin      = $wp_roles->get_role('event_admin');

        $event_admin->add_cap( 'read_event' );
        $event_admin->add_cap( 'delete_event' );
        $event_admin->add_cap( 'edit_event' );
        $event_admin->add_cap( 'read_private_events' );
        $event_admin->add_cap( 'delete_others_events' ); // don't add
        $event_admin->add_cap( 'delete_published_events' );
        $event_admin->add_cap( 'delete_events' ); // don't add
        $event_admin->add_cap( 'edit_others_events' ); // don't add
        $event_admin->add_cap( 'edit_events' );
        $event_admin->add_cap( 'publish_events' ); // don't add
        // edit 1 ends : 

        //echo '<pre>', print_r( $wp_roles, 1), '</pre>';
        //die;
}
add_action('init', 'cloneUserRole');


function stack_event_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Events', 'post type general name', 'stack' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Event', 'post type singular name', 'stack' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Events', 'admin menu', 'stack' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Event', 'add new on admin bar', 'stack' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'event', 'stack' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Event', 'stack' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Event', 'stack' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Event', 'stack' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Event', 'stack' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Events', 'stack' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Events', 'stack' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Events:', 'stack' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No events found.', 'stack' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No events found in Trash.', 'stack' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'stack' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'  => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'event' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'page',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'event', $args );
}
add_action('init', 'stack_event_init');

function my_rewrite_flush() {
    stack_event_init();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'my_rewrite_flush' );
```

1. [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)
2. [Register post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)
3. [Flush Rewrite Rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation)

Comment: I'm forced to grant only certain privileges to this role, since they should not be allowed to publish any content, only create drafts and so on. The role is one of many on a rather large site, where only certain accounts may delete, publish and create content of different types.